# Why pjmedia_snd_port_create(...) fails initializing the sound port?

Tags: c++, c, sip, pjsip

I am trying to initialise a sound port from pjsip and pjsua with the standart pjmedia_snd_port_create but the result is always not successful.

```
pj_caching_pool_init(&cp, &pj_pool_factory_default_policy, 0);

            pool = pj_pool_create(&cp.factory,
                                  "pool1",
                                  4000,
                                  4000,
                                  NULL);

            pjmedia_snd_port *snd_port1 = NULL;

            status = pjmedia_snd_port_create(pool, id1, id1, clock_rate,
                                                 channel_count, samples_per_frame,
                                                 bits_per_sample,
                                                 0, &snd_port1);
```

My device id1 is 0, as i got it from the audio device manager. I`ve tried with the -1 for defaults but always fails me. I have endpoint created with the pjsua2 api from a C++ class, the lib is OK and running, I can create conference bridges also but the sound port fails me. A bit of a hint will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve fixed it with initialising loop, I guess it has nothing to do with the setup, what I need is actually to register all of my playback and rec devices from my hardware.